# How to simplify Swift Enum custom init

Tags: swift

I've crated an Enum with String type. It has two init methods. One is default init method with rawValue and another one is custom init method with intValue. I've written it like this. Is there any simple way to not to use two switch cases?

```
enum Roman: String {
    case I,V,X,L,C,D,M

    var intValue: Int {
        switch self {
        case .I:
            return 1
        //...
        }
    }
    init?(intValue: Int) {
        switch intValue {
        case 1:
            self = .I
        //...
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}

    //Roman to Int
    let number = "XXI".reversed()
                    .map { Roman(rawValue: String($0))?.intValue ?? 0 }
                    .reduce((total: 0, max: 0)) { result, value in
                        let newTotal = result.total + (value < result.max ? -value : value)
                        return (newTotal, max(result.max, value))
                    }.total
```

Comment: No, not really and it is a little strange to have an enum for this in my opinion since you can have combinations of the letters.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I've the logic to join when it has combination of the letters. But my doubt is how can i write a simple enum and able to init with String and int

Comment: I agree with @JoakimDanielson, why not use a Roman Numeral Parser like for example [this one](https://gist.github.com/kumo/a8e1cb1f4b7cff1548c7) and just use String representations. It would probably be best to create an Object and have the object implement the parse functionality

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I disagree. `Roman` might be a terrible name, but it seems like having a `RomanNumeralDigit` enum makes perfect sense, which is then used by the parser

Comment: @Alexander Ok, I can get that but at least it shouldn't have any init methods then but everything set from the start

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Check updated question. I need to change roman -> Int and Int -> Roman. Which is efficient data structure?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Why shouldn't it have any init methods? A parser that consumes this type might ask "I have an X, what number is that"? That should *definitely* be defined on this type.

Comment: @Alexander My bad, I was only referring to the init that took an Int argument

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get rid of the `switch` statements by defining two dictionaries for a bidirectional mapping between the `Int` values and the `enum case`s.

```
enum Roman: String {
    case I, V, X, L, C, D, M

    private static let intValues:[Roman:Int] = [.I:1,.V:5,.X:10,.L:50,.C:100,.D:500,.M:1000]
    private static let mappingDict:[Int:Roman] = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: Roman.intValues.map({ ($1, $0) }))

    var intValue:Int {
        return Roman.intValues[self]!
    }

    init?(intValue:Int){
        guard let roman = Roman.mappingDict[intValue] else { return nil }
        self = roman
    }
}
```

Comment: `Roman.intValues.map({ ($1, $0) })` would be better here instead of `zip` with values and keys. That way there would be only one iteration over collection. Also there's no guarantee that values and keys would be in same order.

Comment: @user28434 you're absolutely right, great improvement. Updated my answer.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I've modified the answer and updated in question. Instead of two dictionaries I've used one array of tuple

Comment: @arunsiva why use an array of tuples? a `Dictionary` works much faster due to constant time element lookup.

Comment: @arunsiva, lookup using `Array` will be `O(n)`, using `Dictionary` will be `O(1)`. So, on average your version of `intValue` and `init?(intValue:)` will take more time.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with Dávid Pásztor's answer, but I do really like Βασίλης Δ.'s thinking raw values. That just seems a very natural approach. So I'd like to bring those's together.

First, starting with Βασίλης Δ.'s code, adding an `intValue` alias just because I think it reads a bit better.

```
enum Roman: Int {
    case I = 1
    case V = 5
    case X = 10
    case L = 50
    case C = 100
    case D = 500
    case M = 1000

    var intValue: Int { return rawValue }
}
```

Then provide a lookup for Strings using the new CaseIterable:

```
extension Roman: CaseIterable {
    enum Error: Swift.Error {
        case invalid
    }

    init<S: StringProtocol>(_ string: S) throws {
        guard let roman = Roman.allCases.first(where: { "\($0)" == string }) else {
            throw Error.invalid
        }
        self = roman
    }

    init(_ character: Character) throws { try self.init(String(character)) }
}
```

With that, I think the `number` algorithm gets a little bit nicer at the top:

```
let number = try "XXI".reversed()
    .map { try Roman($0).intValue }
    .reduce((total: 0, max: 0)) { result, value in
        let newTotal = result.total + (value < result.max ? -value : value)
        return (newTotal, max(result.max, value))
    }.total
```

I'm not a big fan of this algorithm, because it behaves erratically for invalid input, but at least this version rejects invalid characters rather than converting them to 0.

Comment: Βασίλης Δ. Didn't explain how to init with a String or Character. In `guard let roman = Roman.allCases.first(where: { "\($0)" == string }) else {` I thought `"\($0)"` would give its rawValue. Easy solution

Comment: lookup using `let roman = Roman.allCases.first(where: { "\($0)" == string })` will be 0(n) and Dávid Pásztor's ans will be 0(1). Isn't?

Comment: Complexity analysis (big-O) tells you nothing useful about performance for small values of N. A linear search of a 7 item list on average requires 4 equality checks. A dictionary search of a 7 item list requires a hash operation, plus (most likely) 1 equality check. The hash function can take longer than 3 extra equality checks. Dictionaries also introduce significant memory overhead, which may reduce memory locality (not on a dictionary *this* small, but a bit larger). Good locality is often more important than algorithm complexity (big-O), on moderate size N.

Comment: If you want my long-form rant on this particular topic, see https://vimeo.com/218867678 starting around 44:30. :D

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want.. Why don't assign directly the values to the enumerator cases? Ex.

```
    enum Roman: Int {
        case I = 1
        case V = 5
        case X = 10
        case L = 50
        case C = 100
        case D = 500
        case M = 1000
    }
```

And on your main class

```
print(Roman.I.rawValue)
print(Roman(rawValue: 1))
```

Comment: I need to init with "X" to get 10 and init with 10 to get "x"

Comment: Why do you want init() ?

Comment: 1.I have var string:String = "X"; I need to get Int from this string

Comment: 2.I have var num:Int = 10; I need to get Roman letter string from this num