# Int enums with String representation

Tags: swift, enums

I'd like to have an Int enum which can be "serialized" as Int or String as well.

```
enum Fruits : Int {
   case Banana = 1
   case Apple = 123
}

let favorite = Frutis(fromRaw: 1)
let banana = Fruits(from: "Banana")
assert(favorite==banana)
assert(favorite.rawValue == 1)
assert(String(describing: favorite) == "Banana")
```

How can I do that without  implementing init(fromRaw:) and init(from:) myself for all the cases? The enum contains many entries and I'd like to avoid a bloated code.

Comment: Related question: [How to simplify enum custom init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55515924/how-to-simplify-swift-enum-custom-init/55516157?noredirect=1#comment97738196_55516157) (might even be a duplicate). Also bear in mind that the Swift naming convention for enum cases is lowerCamelCase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put this together from the linked answers which supports all conversions.

```
enum Fruits : Int, CaseIterable {
    case banana = 1
    case apple = 123

    init?<S: StringProtocol>(_ string: S) {
        guard let value = Fruits.allCases.first(where: { "\($0)" == string }) else {
            return nil
        }
        self = value
    }
    var stringRepresentation: String {
        return "\(self)"
    }
}

let favorite = Fruits(rawValue: 123)!
let apple = Fruits("apple")!
assert(favorite == apple)
assert(favorite.rawValue == 123)
assert(String(describing: favorite) == "apple")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add it as computed property, like this:

```
enum Fruits: Int {
    case banana = 1
    case apple = 123

    var stringRepresentation: String {
        return "\(self)"
    }
}
```

This way you can use it like this `let favorite = Fruits.banana.stringRepresentation`, and if you'd want to get the Int value you'd just call `.rawValue`.

If you'd want to get an enum value from a string I think you'll have to use something like `init(from: )`.

This will require writing out all possible cases, so it isn't the cleanest code. Depends on what you're trying to accomplish but maybe you could better use a [Dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary) for this.

Comment: This works all ways except String -> Fruits. Who to I get the enum from a String?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to do this dynamically and this will require writing out all possible cases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do exactly what you want. What I've got below is a way to make something similar but it'll take a while to write out if you have a lot of cases.

```swift
enum Fruits : Int {
    case Banana = 1
    case Apple = 123

    var stringValue: String {
        return "\(self)"
    }

    init?(stringValue: String) {
        switch stringValue {
        case "Banana":
            self.init(rawValue: 1)
        case "Apple":
            self.init(rawValue: 123)
        default:
            self.init(rawValue: 0)
        }
    }
}

let favorite = Fruits(rawValue: 1)
let banana = Fruits(stringValue: "Banana")

assert(favorite==banana)
assert(favorite?.rawValue == 1)
assert(favorite?.stringValue == "Banana")
```